# Hide parent li element if the child span element is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, parent

I want to build a jquery supported way to hide an (li) parent element if the child (span) element is empty. I already build such a question but i have no idea why it isn´t working.

```
<li data-column="3" class=„parent“>   
  <span class=„childTitle">Lorem Ipsum</span>:  
  <span class="childValue"><!—child value--><!—child value--></span>  
</li>
```

I tried to build an if question:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if ($('span.childValue').is(':empty')){
$(this).parents().hide();
}     
});
```

I tried also to build an simple function:

```
$("span.childValue:empty").parent().hide();
```

But either dosn´t work. The finished code shall build in a wordpress child theme javascript. I tried different ways but none of it had a result.

Comment: What's up with the weird quotes in your attributes?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried also to build an simple function:
>
> ```
>  $("span.childValue:empty").parent().hide();
> ```

That *will* work fine if you just wrap it in a document ready handler.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("span.childValue:empty").parent().hide();   
});
```

(You'll also need to fix all the weird quote characters in your html.)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jphuftqu/

Regarding the version you tried with the `if` statement, that wouldn't work because the value of `this` is associated with the function that it is in, not with an `if` block, so `$(this).parents()` has nothing to do with the span.

In the `if` you would have to get the parent of the element with `$('span.childValue').parent()`, but if you have multiple list items of the same structure that would select all of them so that's not what you want.

Note also that in the `if` version that you tried you were using `.parents()`, which would get all of the ancestors of the span. Use `.parent()` or `.closest('li')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the weird quotes in your example code you can use this:

```
$('span.childValue').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':empty')) $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gbo4opv7/)**

Note that you want to use `parent()`, not `parents()` to hide the `<li>`